# CryptoJs SHA256 to Base64url wrong value

Tags: javascript, typescript, cryptojs

I have the following code:

```js
import Base64url from "crypto-js/enc-base64url"
import SHA256 from "crypto-js/sha256";

//... 

const codeVerifier = "test-value";
const hashed = SHA256(codeVerifier);


console.log({ sha256: hashed.toString() });
// output: sha256: 5b1406fffc9de5537eb35a845kc99521f26fba0e772d58b42e09f4221b9e043ae

console.log({ base64: Base64url.stringify(hashed) })
// output: base64: WxQG__yd5VN-s1qEXJlSHyb7oOdy1YtC4J9CIbngQ64

// expected: base64: NWIxNDA2ZmZmYzlkZTU1MzdlYjM1YTg0NWM5OTUyMWYyNmZiYTBlNzcyZDU4YjQyZTA5ZjQyMjFiOWUwNDNhZQ
```

As you can see the output that I'm getting is incorrect (I used an online base64url generator to validate, such as [this one](https://base64.guru/standards/base64url/encode)). I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong here, but I can't see it. I read the documentation and couldn't find anything.

I've prepared a small [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-wiles-pxkp1n?file=/src/App.tsx) if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after searching a bit more, here is what I did:

```js
const codeVerifier = "test-value";
const hashed = SHA256(codeVerifier);

// parse to utf-8-encoded data
const utf8parsed = Utf8.parse(hashed.toString());

console.log({ sha256: hashed.toString() });
// output: sha256: 5b1406fffc9de5537eb35a845kc99521f26fba0e772d58b42e09f4221b9e043ae

console.log({ base64: Base64url.stringify(utf8parsed) });
// correct output!
```

Thanks to others that helped (@ZombieChowder)!

Answer (score 2):

What you are experiencing is related to the CryptoJS package since I saw that you are using **crypto-js/enc-base64url** inside your codebox example.

Objects in CryptoJS are WordArray types, meaning that when you call **toString()** on such an object, you get a Hex-encoded string of that binary object. However, if you print `result.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)` then you get the Base64-encoded string of the binary result.

If you take your assigned variable and directly encode it to **Base64**, then it is probably assumed that a is already a string (e.g. UTF-8 encoded). The online calculators that you are using for validation don't know that it is Hex-encoded.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thank you, this actually helped a lot, I've posted my solution. If you want copy it as yours and I'll accept it as an answer (and remove mine).

Comment: nah, it's all good.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want base64 encoded hex string of the hash and crypto-js library's base64 encoder doesn't accept strings, you can use [`btoa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/btoa).

```
btoa(hashed.toString())
```

But than might not what you want, if you actually need the Base64url variant.